# The command dal:create:schema does not create foreign keys

Tags: shopware6

Given the following example for an Entity-Definition, there is a foreign key defined. As a developer and database engineer i would expect that the command `dal:create:schema` would also create the expected foreign keys. But this is not the case.

```
 return new FieldCollection([
    (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),

    (new LongTextField('comment', 'name'))->addFlags(new Required()),

    (new FkField('order_id', 'orderId', OrderDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
    new OneToOneAssociationField('order', 'order_id', 'id', OrderDefinition::class, false),

            new CreatedAtField(),
            new UpdatedAtField()
        ]);
```

Instead this is the result:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_refund` (
    `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `comment` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `order_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

However, it seems like that ManyToOneAssociations will add foreign keys. Is there something missing in the entity definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you mentioned is using the SchemaGenerator which has a method to generate Foreign keys:

[`\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\SchemaGenerator::generateForeignKeys`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e7b576a0df3d9e6e6daaf69b3a2f665f64f79c3f/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/SchemaGenerator.php#L218)

Looking at this method it seems to work only fields of the type `ManyToOneAssociationField`

```
private function generateForeignKeys(EntityDefinition $definition): string
{
    $fields = $definition->getFields()->filter(
        function (Field $field) {
            if (!$field instanceof ManyToOneAssociationField) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    );
```

I also think it is a shortcoming of this function that it does not generate foreign keys for fields of the type `OneToOneAssociationField`. Maybe you can try to adjust this filtering and see if it works and make a pull request on GitHub for the benefit of yourself and other developers?

Comment: Thanks for your research. The question is more about if there is a specific reason, why this has not been included. It might be an architecture decision. 

I will create an issue in Github.